# Return exact value in Rust HashMap

Tags: get, hashmap, rust, key

I can't find a suitable way to return the exact value of key in a `HashMap` in Rust . All the existing `get` methods return in a different format rather than the exact format.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question isn't as clear as it could be. Could you clarify it a bit? What do you mean by "exact format"? Do you mean the exact type? It would help if you provide a snippet of code that you think should work but doesn't :)

Comment: not sure if the question has been edited but it makes perfect sense to me FWIW

Comment: The problem is the word "format" makes the question unclear and ambiguous. `HashMap<T>.get(k)` returns an `Option<&T>`. If the question author intends to ask why the value is wrapped in an Option, then the existing answer seems to answer the question well. If the poster instead intends to ask why a reference to the value is returned, another answer would be appropriate. But without more clarity in the question we can't tell which of those things are being asked.

Answer (score 11):

You probably want the [`HashMap::remove` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.remove) - it deletes the key from the map and returns the original value rather than a reference:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Thing {
    content: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut hm: HashMap<u32, Thing> = HashMap::new();
    hm.insert(
        123,
        Thing {
            content: "abc".into(),
        },
    );
    hm.insert(
        432,
        Thing {
            content: "def".into(),
        },
    );

    // Remove object from map, and take ownership of it
    let value = hm.remove(&432);

    if let Some(v) = value {
        println!("Took ownership of Thing with content {:?}", v.content);
    };
}
```

The `get` methods must return a reference to the object because the original object can only exist in one place (it is owned by the `HashMap`). The `remove` method can return the original object (i.e "take ownership") only because it removes it from its original owner.

Another solution, depending on the specific situation, may be to take the reference, call `.clone()` on it to make a new copy of the object (in this case it wouldn't work because `Clone` isn't implemented for our `Thing` example object - but it would work if the value way, say, a `String`)

Finally it may be worth noting you can still use the reference to the object in many circumstances - e.g the previous example could be done by getting a reference:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Thing {
    content: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut hm: HashMap<u32, Thing> = HashMap::new();
    hm.insert(
        123,
        Thing {
            content: "abc".into(),
        },
    );
    hm.insert(
        432,
        Thing {
            content: "def".into(),
        },
    );

    let value = hm.get(&432); // Get reference to the Thing containing "def" instead of removing it from the map and taking ownership

    // Print the `content` as in previous example.
    if let Some(v) = value {
        println!("Showing content of referenced Thing: {:?}", v.content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two basic methods of obtaining the value for the given key: [`get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) and [`get_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut). Use the first one if you just want to read the value, and the second one if you need to modify the value:

```
fn get(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
fn get_mut(&mut self, k: &Q) -> Option<&mut V>
```

As you can see from their signatures, both of these methods return [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) rather than a direct value. The reason is that there may be no value associated to the given key:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert(1, "a");
assert_eq!(map.get(&1), Some(&"a")); // key exists
assert_eq!(map.get(&2), None);       // key does not exist
```

If you are sure that the map contains the given key, you can use [`unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) to get the value out of the option:

```
assert_eq!(map.get(&1).unwrap(), &"a");
```

However, in general, it is better (and safer) to consider also the case when the key might not exist. For example, you may use [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html):

```
if let Some(value) = map.get(&1) {
    assert_eq!(value, &"a");
} else {
    // There is no value associated to the given key.
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is, that the returned thing is a reference, rather than a value.